# dict to csv - create column headers dynamically depending on dict keys available

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have built a scraper that collects court details, and for each court I get a dictionary that contains dictionaries, like this:

```
my_dict = {'url': u'https://courttribunalfinder.service.gov.uk//courts/east-berkshire-magistrates-court-slough', 'court': u"East Berkshire Magistrates' Court, Slough", 'pros': {u'Crown Court location code': u'1920'}, 'contact:': {'telephone - Pay a fine:': u'0300  790 9901', 'email - Enquiries:': u'tv-berkshiremcenq@hmcts.gsi.gov.uk', 'telephone - Fine queries:': u'01869 8532900870 240 5995', 'telephone - Family queries:': u'01869 987 0500', 'telephone - Enquiries:': u'0118  980 1800', 'telephone - Witness service:': u'0300 332 1000', 'telephone - Fax:': u'0870 324 0038'}, 'address': [{u'visiting': {u'addressLocality': u'Slough', u'addressRegion': u'Berkshire', u'streetAddress': [u'Law Courts', u'Chalvey Park', u'Off Windsor Road'], u'postalCode': u'SL1 2HJ'}}, {u'postal': [u"Admin Centre, Reading Magistrates' Court", u'Castle Street', u'Reading', u'Berkshire', u'RG1 7TQ']}]}
```

I want to write to csv using the `keys()` as the csv file column headers. I do this by assigning a variable to the corresponding key.

```
court_name = my_dict.keys()[i]
```

where `i` is the corresponding index number for the key in `my_dict` ("*East Berkshire Magistrates' Court, Slough*", from my example)

Some courts only have a visiting address, no postal address, and vice versa. Others might add more details over time. So far my scraper builds the dict dynamically by assigning the (BeautifulSoup) `element.text` as the value and the corresponding `element.attrs` as the key, for whatever is available on the website.

Assigning a variable for each of the column headers seems a little less than ideal given that I've collected all that info.

Is there a way to create column headers dynamically based on the `keys()` available in the `dict`?

Comment: CSV might not be the best data structure if you want to change the header for each row. You can create a header with every possible field, and add a space where you don't have the information. To get the key of the dict, you can use `list(a.keys())`. Also, take a look at the CSV module, especially the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

Comment: I am using DictWriter, have read the docs, but they don't cover the logic needed. To clarify - I don't want a different header for each row - each unique key should be a **column** header (i.e. `keys()` just go into the first row). My planned logic is something like "If a new key is found, a new column header should be created, else slot the value under the existing header"

Comment: The simple solution is to recreate the CSV each time you found a new key, and add a NULL value to the other entries in the CSV (if you cannot know all the possible keys). If you already know all the possible key you might have, you can only specify them once in the `fieldnames`. Even if the current data you are trying to put in your CSV doesnt have the field, the writer will place a blank.